# How to Open csv file with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

There is a CSV format file with three column dataframe.
The third column has long text.
This error message occurred, when i tried to open the file using `pandas.read_csv`

```
message : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 0: invalid start byte.
```

But there is no problem opening the file with

```
with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors = "ignore") as csvfile:
```

I don't know how converting this data to dataframe and i don't think `pandas.read_csv` handle this error properly.

So, how can i open this file and get dataframe?

Comment: Have you specified the encoding when using pandas.read_csv(), as in: pandas.read_csv(encoding="utf-8")?

Comment: use pandas.read_csv()

Comment: @woblers Yes, but i got the same message..

Comment: typo   read.csv() -> read_csv()

Comment: You should post here a sample of your csv file- say top 5 rows.

Comment: You can also try other encodings. I've found instances where "utf-8" works with most libraries, but inexplicably pandas prefers "latin-1".

Answer (score 7):

**Try this:**

Open the cvs file in a text editor and make sure to save it in utf-8 format.

Then read the file as normal:

```
import pandas
csvfile = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the built-in csv reader then put the data into pandas.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
         print(', '.join(row))
```

If this doesn't work, then at least you can confirm that it is a csv issue and not a pandas issue choking on encodings.

The other recommendation is to ensure you are using Python 3.x that handles encoding issues much better than 2.7.

If you can provide your sample, I can test it myself and update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another option for encoding as "ISO-8859-1"

In your case:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', errors = "ignore") as csvfile:
```

or try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
print(data_file)
```